# NodeJS Do work In The Background

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two requirements in NodeJS and since I am coming from C/C++ Embedded systems I am unable to decide the best way to do it (I have played around with Promise/Mongoose/Async etc and now relatively comfortable in NodeJS).

1. Suppose there are 100,000 clients interacting with my NodeJS Application. Say I want to monitor HeartBeat (Every client is supposed to send a small information after every 10 Minutes saying I am alive and if I do not receive HeartBeat after 10 Minutes from a particular client then I am supposed to take some action like for example sending an Email to that client). How to do this in a perfect/textbook best recommended way (Scalable). I do not feel that forking some 100,000 threads for 100,000 clients is a good choice. There must be some good design to tackle this problem in NodeJS
2. If I have to send SMS/Email and PUSH notification (Say in different scenarios) say you have an intrusion alert in your vehicle and say in the meantime another vehicle has raised ECALL etc (All in parallel). I want to delegate the responsibility of sending Email/SMS/PUSH to some worker. Main application will simply PUSH this WORK of sending Email/SMS/PUSH (With Data/Address etc) to that worker (Will keep on pushing those details to worker as and when situation arise) and worker will deal with the job of actually sending SMS/Email/PUSH (And associated retry strategy). Multiple scenarios can occur simultaneously for multiple vehicles (one vehicle raises ECALL and another Intrusion Alert and hence different Email/SMS/PUSH with different content and address)

How to tackle these two job in a TextBook recommended NodeJS approach without compromising on scalability and in an elegant fashion.

Comment: How about `socket.io` ?

Comment: There's no "textbook" solution to this. It's a very broad topic with many possible ways of handling it. You'll have to do some research and decide what works best for you. I will say that if you expect to have 100,000 concurrent connections, you're going to need multiple servers to distribute the load.

Comment: @Rayon Socket.io just provides a WebSockets connection, usually between a server and a client. I fail to see how this addresses OPs questions.

Comment: Yes, to communicate among client-server... As far as `load` is concerned, some sort of `load-balancer` could be introduced as per the number of concurrent requests, which will scale the hardware as per the need...

Comment: @Mike/Rayon: How you would have tackled a design problem like this ? I don't have NodeJS expertise to make an informed design decision regarding the same.

Comment: @AbhishekDhar Like I said, it's a very broad topic with people going through a lot of education to come up with intelligent designs. The answer to this question would be much too broad and [doesn't really fit the SO format.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Would you recommend NodeJS KUE (Job Queue) to tackle Problem#2 ?

Comment: Is STOMP a good answer for Problem#1 ?

Comment: Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I can also honestly say, I have never worked with either of those technologies nor am I an expert in this area.